# How costly is it to store content in a box register?

Tags: tex-core, boxes, comparison, performance

I wonder how costly it is in terms of compilations speed and also other terms like memory etc., to store some content in a box and use this box then afterwards only once (or maybe twice). Is the difference meaningless or significant if used often in a document?

I'm talking about something like

```
{\sbox\mybox{<some content>}% or \setbox\mybox\hbox{..}
 <calculated something depended on the box dimension>
 \box\mybox
 % or:
 % \usebox\mybox
}
```

Also: how big is the difference between using `\box` and `\usebox` (which requires to copy the box)? In some scenarios I can't be sure that the box isn't required again and can't use `\box` in general.

I'm coding several macros similar to `\raisebox` which store their content into a box and allow the user to access the dimensions using the macros `\height`, `\width` and others. During the normal use these macros might often be cascaded and each of it would simply re-save the saved box of the inner macro (`\sbox\mybox{\sbox\mybox{..} .. \usebox\mybox} .. \usebox\mybox`). So I wonder if I should program these macros in a way so that they can reuse the box register of the inner macro in such cases or if this would be overkill?

Comment: Saying `\copy\x` or `\box\x` costs the same, the former is less efficient for memory because it doesn't free the register, which is cleared anyway when the group ends. One has to pay attention to a peculiarity of box registers: `\setbox0=\hbox{x}{\box0}` results in an *empty* box register 0, because `\box` clears the contents of the most recent instance of the register, which in this case happens to live at an upper level.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks! That's a very important point I wanted to investigate anyway.

Comment: @egreg: Ok, I looked at this a little and figured that a `\setbox0=\copy0` copies the existing box 0 to a local assigned box 0, so `\box0` clears the local assignment while the one in the parent scope is unchanged. This is nice if you want to `\copy` the box but e.g. with adjusted height and depth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Saying `\copy\x` or `\box\x` costs the same, the former is less efficient for memory because it doesn't free the register, which is cleared anyway when the group ends.

One has to pay attention to a peculiarity of box registers: `\setbox0=\hbox{x}{\box0}` results in an empty box register 0, because `\box` clears the contents of the most recent instance of the register, which in this case happens to live at an upper level.

As Martin remarks,

```
\begingroup
\setbox0=\copy0
<code>
\endgroup
```

creates a local copy of `\box0` and inside the group one can do many things to `\box0` without worrying about the box register at the upper level.

If I compile a file consisting of 10000 copies of a box built simply with \hbox I get

> `real 0m0.524s`
>   `user 0m0.458s`
>   `sys  0m0.054s`

If I say instead `\setbox0=\hbox{...}\box0`, I get

> `real 0m0.529s`
>   `user 0m0.460s`
>   `sys  0m0.054s`

Not a big difference.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What would be the overhead of using `\setbox` to store the content and then use `\box` to typeset it versus typesetting it directly?

Comment: I repeated this now with 1.000.000 copies but using `\sbox` with and without `xcolor` to get the overhead of the color stack into account. Results (real): hbox 1m36s, sbox 1m46s, sbox with xcolor 1m49s, averaged over 3 runs each on a ramdisk to avoid HD caching etc. impacts. The file size is indentical in the first two cases (12480175 byte) but 2.5% larger with the color support (12798580 byte). Conclusions: There is an impact, especially with colors, but for normal documents it should be negligent. I accept the answer now. Thanks for the update.